# How do I the change the host name in C#?

Tags: c#, hostname

I want to change the hostname by code in c#.
The operating system is xp.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the computer name or the dns host name?

Answer (score 2):

```
ManagementClass mComputerSystem = new ManagementClass("Win32_ComputerSystem");
ManagementBaseObject outParams;
ManagementBaseObject objNewComputerName = mComputerSystem.GetMethodParameters("Rename");
objNewComputerName["Name"] = "NEWNAMEHERE";
outParams = mComputerSystem.InvokeMethod("Rename", objNewComputerName, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit these registry keys, and reboot. Note you could try just restarting the Computer Browser and Server and Client services, it might work, but I doubt it.

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Hostname
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\NV Hostname
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName\ComputerName
```